# Unit testing an EmberJS App (an actual unit test)

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, ember.js

I want to premise that I'm aware of Ember QUnit (recently covered at EmberConf) as well as using PhantomJS so please read my points in question closely if you're thinking of marking as a duplicate.

My goal is to run unit tests from the command line, similar to a mocha test might run

`mocha simple_test.js`

and see the results in the form of a command line reporter.

1. testing ember modules in isolation. I would like to be able to new-up an ember object, route, or controller without the context of a running ember app (perhaps some kind of ember test harness) and run assertions against that module.
2. testing ember modules in the command line (avoiding browser reporters like QUnit or headless browsers like PhantomJS)

I already have integration and acceptance tests using a combination of karma and phantomjs, I would like to see if I can compliment with more unit tests.  Has anybody come across a unit test setup similar to to what I listed above or is it not really possible and/or productive?

**Update**
The ember guides list unit testing strategies here:
http://emberjs.com/guides/testing/unit/

In my opinion, these seem more like integration tests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah I do this with my application. You might like to look at the new testing guides in the ember site's documenation if you haven't already seen it (it went live last week sometime). I helped edit it. It's pretty good! :-)

Good luck and let me know if you need any more help, like I say, I do unit tests all the time on all parts of Ember. The hardest so far for me has been components because they're neither integration nor unit, really... they're like a hybrid: isolated integration unit tests that still require large parts of ember and rendering in the view.

I run headless using guard, jasmine **and** qunit. Jasmine's my preference and I've been moving over from qunit slowly.

http://emberjs.com/guides/testing/

Also I noticed that what you seem to want is to isolate the units outside of even ember itself. To do that, I'd put your code in separate javascript libraries... otherwise you'll have troubles: afterall how are you going to unit test a piece of code without Ember present if it uses Ember?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I think I'm still trying to refine exactly what I'm asking but I know I would like to write a test against an ember app without a browser or headless browser as mentioned above.  Possibly looking for an ember test harness perhaps? I have some integration tests similar to a strategy you mentioned but I'm striving for something closer to a unit test.  When I say unit test, I think of test in isolation.  The ember guide to unit testing here, http://emberjs.com/guides/testing/unit/ to me misses the value of a unit test, they still look like integration tests

Comment: Yeah, kind of. Ember is a front-side application framework as you know. There's no reason you can't unit test your ember objects, is there? I don't know why there isn't? I've done it quite a lot. It's just like unit testing any other piece of javascript code. Very very simple. What do you need help with?

Comment: Irrespective of what you do, you need a javascript runtime, obviously. It makes little sense to test ember outside of the context of the browser (even headless), seeing as that's where your code WILL execute. Also, I'm not sure if you're aware of this, but you **MIGHT** not encounter problems that ordinarily would manifest because of the way browser javascript runtimes execute javascript differently than non-browser runtimes. Because ember is a web app framework, you **should** test in that context, always, IMHO.

Comment: For a bit more detail, I'm thinking in terms of server side node and ember without the context of browser (headless or otherwise).  I realize I'm pushing the current boundaries that normal ember apps work within so its very likely what I'm looking for isnt quite available yet but I'm sure I'm not the only one thinking along these lines :)  Thanks again for your replies.

Comment: I'm marking this as an answer as this is probably the status quo for ember as it relates to unit testing but will update accordingly.

Comment: @JustinSoliz I'm very interested in what you find and also discussing this with you more. I'm a massive fan of TDD (and Kent Beck in general), as well as separation of concerns, so if you can enunciate a bit more clearly the advantages of a cleaner testing context, I'm interested and listening :)

Comment: @JustinSoliz it's probably worth your while taking a look at the ember-cli project if you haven't already because this uses a bunch of interesting tech and seems to be the driving force behind moving away from ruby & rails as being the "standard" ember server side tech. A voice around super clean unit testing on the server without a browser might be a useful addition to it. I'm just not 100% sure if Ember even runs outside a browser context. If that's true, you won't be able to write unit tests that depend on it outside of a browser, right?

Comment: @JustinSoliz you've probably seen this already, but if you haven't, it'd be good to check it out:
http://www.confreaks.com/videos/3310-emberconf2014-the-unofficial-official-ember-testing-guide  it's eric berry's talk at emberconf where amongst other things, he talks about how to unit test things with ember-qunit.

Comment: yea we're working through a pretty large scale project so havent had too much time to hit this. It looks like I'll be running into stefan here: http://www.meetup.com/Ember-js-Seattle-Meetup/events/68418882/ so I'll definitely get his thoughts and strategies and get back to you.

Comment: Awesome :) Hehe... so jealous :) :)